# Как вычислять точки привязки к 3D модели?

Tags: c#, математика, unity3d, 3d, vector

Есть функция, похожая на привязку точек 3д модели к скелету (skinning) только с одной костью:

```
Vector3 skinedPoint (Matrix4x4 bindPose, Matrix4x4 pose, Vector3 bindPoint, float bindWeight ){
   Vector3 local = bindPose.inverse.MultiplyPoint3x4(bindPoint);
   return  bindPoint*(1-bindWeight) + pose.MultiplyPoint3x4(local)*bindWeight;
}
```

Мне нужна функция, которая обратная приведенной выше функции и вычисляет bindPoint, то есть:

```
Vector3 bindPoint (Matrix4x4 bindPose, Matrix4x4 pose, Vector3 skinedPoint, float bindWeight){
   return ????
}
```

Вот функция умножения матрицы на вектор которая используется.

```
public Vector3 MultiplyPoint3x4 (Vector3 v)
{
    Vector3 result;
    result.x = this.m00 * v.x + this.m01 * v.y + this.m02 * v.z +   this.m03;
    result.y = this.m10 * v.x + this.m11 * v.y + this.m12 * v.z + this.m13;
    result.z = this.m20 * v.x + this.m21 * v.y + this.m22 * v.z + this.m23;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: поправьте заголовок - опечатка в слове *при**вз**яки*

Answer (score 1):

Введем более короткие обозначения:

- X-искомая матрица.
- Q-матрица, у которой на всех местах стоят bindWeight
- E-матрица, у которой на всех местах стоят 1
- C-матрица, обратная к BindPose
- P-pose

Тогда первая функция записывается как

```
S=X*(E-Q)+P*C*X*Q

S=X*(E-Q+P*C*Q)
```

Искомое уравнение:

```
X=S*(E-Q+P*C*Q)^-1;
```

Comment: Уважаемый Николас.  Мне бы ответ С# кодом, потому что сложно понять, например, такие термины как "матрица, у которой на всех местах стоят 1" или знак "^"

Comment: @polystep термины стандартные для математики. E - матрица, заполненная единичками.
^-1 означает, что матрицу в скобках нужно обратить. Если у вас все настолько плохо с математикой, исправляйте этот пробел.